# Drupal Paragraph Type that references a Block from a View

Tags: views, 8, nodes, blocks, paragraphs

I have a paragraph type that is called view reference, the field within view reference is an entity reference to a view.

I've recently upgraded my drupal site from 8.3 > 8.4.5. The problem is that now - when I view the rendered node and paragraph type when logged in the view shows. But when I'm logged out the view is not there.

I've looked into the problem and for some reason the field isn't rendering i.e. past the *views-element-inner* tag, see the following screenshots:

Logged in:
[image: logged in image]

Logged out:
[image: logged out image]

Can anyone help me with a solution?

My plan B is to scrap the view reference paragraph field and replace it with a block field inside my paragraph type with the block field module. Can anyone back me up on this or suggest another solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S. I've also had a look at the anonymous user and made sure that all my media/views/fields/paragraph types have the "view/access" content permissions.

Comment: I seem to remember 8.4 tightened up on requiring views to have specific permissions defined.  In your view, do you have a permission set.  E.g. access content?

Comment: @CGMonroe yeah it did have the "access content" permission on the view. I removed it, but still... the problem persists.

Comment: Not sure what the specific problem is, we are using https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field. An entity refernce field doesn't have any settings, so not sure how you select display and arguments. The block field allows all the block-level functionality of views, even arguments through context (with a not-yet-committed patch for block_content)